# Send image as an attachment in browser

Tags: python, browser, flask

I have a static folder that is managed by apache where images are stored.
I wonder if it's possible by configuring apache to send all files from that folder as downloadable files, not opening them as images inside browser? I suppose I can do it by creating a special view in Flask, but I think it would be nicer if I could do it with some more simple solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`flask.send_from_directory`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.send_from_directory) with `as_attachment=True` argument can do this.

Also, you can configure Apache to send `Content-Disposition: attachment` header like in [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/101966)

Answer (score 1):

You can force the contents to be a downloadable attachment using http headers.

In PHP that would be:

> $fileName = 'dummy.jpg';
>
> header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$fileName");

Then, the script dumps the raw contents of the file.